# Is there a way to assign the results of one SQL query into 2 dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, sql

I am using the pyodbc library and have a query that returns 2 result sets:

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=ExampleServer;Trusted_Connection=yes;")
query =
    "
    select top 10 * from table 1
    select top 10 * from table 2
    "
df = pd.read_sql(query,cnxn)
```

I want each result set to be a separate dataframe but am unsure of how to achieve this. Any help appreciated and thank you.

Comment: Splitting it up into `df1 = pd.read_excel('SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table1', cnxn)` and `df2 = pd.read_excel('SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table2', cnxn)` wouldn't work?

Comment: Well, the example I used was probably too simplistic, but no. This is from sql server, not excel by the way. What I really want to do is pull a long running query into a temp table, then run 2 queries against that temp table. I don't want the performance hit of running essentially the same query twice.

Comment: Sorry, `read_excel` was a typo; should have been `read_sql`.